# Foreach loop is not working in cronjob in php

Tags: php, cron

I have written a script to check only CSV files and delete them.

```
$dir = $getData['ftp_location']; //get the dir locations from db
echo $dir;
echo nl2br("\n"); 

$files = glob("$dir/*.csv"); //get only csv files

echo $files;
echo nl2br("\n");

foreach ($files as $tmpname)
{
   //do some stuff. I have also done echo here it is not working.
   echo "File Deleted";
}
```

So I tried a simple foreach code like this:

```
$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");

foreach ($colors as $value) 
{
      echo "$value <br>";
}
```

Note: On every run, I get an email stating cronjob ran successfully with the echo printed.

Email like this:

./files/pvc/
Array

I don't get the echo inside the foreach loop.

Like "file deleted" or "colors"

If I run the same code directly it is working fine but not via cronjob. Any idea why?

Comment: [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) does indeed return an array, so the email is correct.

Comment: Yes but I don't get the echo inside foreach. For a simple code like print colors inside array.

Comment: OK. There might be a bug in your code. Check the PHP error log. Another thing that might be a problem is the directory from which the script runs. It might not be the same when you use the script directly and when you use cron. Make sure the directory, and the file paths, start at the root of the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because csv path is relative path.

When cron is executed, the current directory path is the same as the php binary path(ex: /usr/bin/php).

Please use the absolute path.

```
$dir = __DIR__. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $getData['ftp_location']; //get the dir locations from db
```